# How to find the list of docker container Ids except one of them?

Tags: linux, windows, docker, containers

How do you find the ids of the running docker containers except one of them on Windows and Linux?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows using PowerShell:

- docker ps -a

.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE            ...
f5c666d132d9        1.1.1.1:1111/img1 ...
80ac3c2a1ef9        1.1.1.1:1111/img2 ...
5bfbc8605b59        1.1.1.1:1111/img3 ...
aba1aa6f12b8        1.1.1.1:1111/img4 ...
```

Let's say I want all ids except the id of the container created from img3

```
docker ps -a | Out-String -Stream | Select-String -Pattern ("img3") -NotMatch| Select-String -Pattern ("CONTAINER") -NotMatch| ForEach-Object{($_ -split "\s+")[0]}
```

result :

```
f5c666d132d9

80ac3c2a1ef9

aba1aa6f12b8
```

Answer (score 0):

you can  use

```
docker container ls | grep -v "a8d88c7291f0" | cut -f 1 -d ' '
```